# Manually adjusting statistics for raster symbology using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, symbology

In ArcMap I can adjust Mean and Std Dev of a raster to get the stretched symbology I want, left side of screenshot.

In ArcGIS Pro Mean and Std Dev are locked.

How can I change them manually?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stretch is set to custom. Stdev is not relevant to custom stretch so is disabled (you adjust the histogram manually).

Set Primary symbology to Stretch, change Stretch Type to Standard Deviation, change Statistics to Custom, specify your desired statistics:

[image]

[image]